# Formset object has no attribute 'absolute_max'

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I want to create bills in my app. I have one extra_bill_form and multible item_forms.

view:

```
def ExtraBillView(request):
    item_form_set = formset_factory(ItemForm, formset=BaseItemFormSet, can_delete=True)
    extra_bill_form = ExtraBillForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        item_form_set = BaseItemFormSet(request.POST)
        extra_bill_form = ExtraBillForm(request.POST)

        if extra_bill_form.is_valid() and item_form_set.is_valid():
            al1 = extra_bill_form.cleaned_data.get('adress_line1')
            al2 = extra_bill_form.cleaned_data.get('adress_line2')
            al3 = extra_bill_form.cleaned_data.get('adress_line3')
            al4 = extra_bill_form.cleaned_data.get('adress_line4')

            for form in item_form_set:
                pass
        pdb.set_trace()

        else:
            extra_bill_form = ExtraBillForm()
            item_form_set = formset_factory(ItemForm, formset=BaseItemFormSet, extra=0, max_num=5, min_num=1)

    context = {
        'extra_bill_form': extra_bill_form,
        'item_form_set': item_form_set,
    }

    return render(request, 'extra_bill.html', context)
```

form:

```
class ExtraBillForm(forms.Form):
    adress_line1 = forms.CharField(label='Adresszeile 1:', required=True)
    adress_line2 = forms.CharField(label='Adresszeile 2:', required=False)
    adress_line3 = forms.CharField(label='Adresszeile 3:', required=False)
    adress_line4 = forms.CharField(label='Adresszeile 4:', required=False)


class ItemForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label='Artikelname:')
    ust = forms.IntegerField(label='UST:', initial=20)
    price_nto = forms.IntegerField(label='Preis netto:', required=False)
    price_brt = forms.IntegerField(label='Preis brutto:', required=False)


class BaseItemFormSet(BaseFormSet):
    def clean(self):
        if self.price_nto is None:
            if self.price_brt is None:
                return
        if any(self.errors):
            return
```

If I submitt my forms, I get an error:

> 'BaseItemFormSet' object has no attribute 'absolute_max'
>   how to solve this problem?

```
Environment:
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/calculator/extrabill/

Django Version: 1.9.4
Python Version: 3.5.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django_ajax',
 'django_bootstrap_dynamic_formsets',
 'Bank',
 'bootstrap3',
 'Building',
 'Calculator',
 'CounterChange',
 'Customer',
 'Credit',
 'Hackgut',
 'Heatingplant',
 'Index',
 'jquery',
 'jquery_ui',
 'Measurement',
 'Price',
 'Rate']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']

Traceback:

File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  149. response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  147. response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

 File "/home/klaus/PycharmProjects/waerme/Calculator/views.py" in ExtraBillView
  94. if extra_bill_form.is_valid() and item_form_set.is_valid():

 File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py" in is_valid
  316. self.errors

 File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py" in errors
  290. self.full_clean()

File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py" in full_clean
  337. for i in range(0, self.total_form_count()):

File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py" in total_form_count
  116. return min(self.management_form.cleaned_data[TOTAL_FORM_COUNT], self.absolute_max)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /calculator/extrabill/
Exception Value: 'BaseItemFormSet' object has no attribute 'absolute_max'
```

Comment: Please, post the full traceback.

Comment: here the full traceback http://dpaste.com/17NGSX6

Comment: Instead of linking to pastebins, could you just add it to the question as a chunk of code? Also, that's not the traceback, but a piece of surrounding code and list of INSTALLED_APPS and middlewares.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The formset factory creates the formset class. You should only call `formset_factory` once. You can do this outside of the view.

```
ItemFormSet = formset_factory(ItemForm, formset=BaseItemFormSet, extra=0, max_num=5, min_num=1)
```

Then, in your view, instantiate the `ItemFormSet` that was created by `formset_factory`. You shouldn't instantiate `BaseItemFormSet`.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    item_form_set = ItemFormSet(request.POST)
    ...
else:
    item_form_set = ItemFormSet() # blank formset for GET request

context = {
    'extra_bill_form': extra_bill_form,
    'item_form_set': item_form_set,
}

return render(request, 'extra_bill.html', context)
```